# View data use condition if from data got from database in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem, this data I get from database:

```
Array{
[0] => Array(
         [repairstatus] => Mayor
         [unitname] => Financial Bureau
         [isacademic] => T
         [count] => 1
    )
[1] => Array(
         [repairstatus] => Mayor
         [unitname] => Medic
         [isacademic] => Y
         [count] => 1
    )
[2] => Array(
         [repairstatus] => Minor
         [unitname] => Security
         [isacademic] => Y
         [count] => 2
    )
}
```

After this I want to view data unitname and count based on first condition if isacademic then condition if repairstatus using PHP.

Comment: where are your codes that you trying to do.?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you need... Can you please add desire output?

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop twice.

first loop through the each index of array 0,1,3..

inside that foreach, again loop through those indexes to get the values.

like:

```
$collections = //store query data

foreach($collections as $collection){
    foreach($collection as $data){
        // here you can access repairstatus,unitname, isacademic, count.
}

}
```

Another thing, I would suggest you to use is_academic as boolean field, seems you are using string to put T/F . but better practice to put any is_something value to boolean in db.

Comment: Thanks for you, but i want to ask, how if we want to view data unitname and count based on condition if isacademic like Y or T, like this, if isacademic same Y view data unitname and count just based on isacademic Y in second, foreach

Comment: Then please edit your question and show some code u r trying to do. are you using any framework ? or just raw php? 

the method I've specified above? if you are using raw php and no framework / design pattern , u can simply put that foreach inside your html in a php scope to echo / condition / compare the property like $data->unitname; $data->count, $data->isacademic etc.

Comment: i have post whats output i need sir, i need to make data like that, have if condition based on isacademic Y/T please help me, and thank you for your respond